# javascript variable into php form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I can now display the total price of a javascript var on the page. But I also want to send this value with the form once it is submitted. Is there any way to do this? (Everything is embedded in a normal form)

```
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

script

```
var Price = getstatus() + getroom() * getdays()

//display the result
var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
divobj.style.display='block';
divobj.innerHTML = "The total cost is €"+Price;
```

Comment: Java **IS NOT** Javascript

Comment: You could save the `price` in an input that may be visible for users like `<input type="text" />` or using a hidden `<input type="hidden" />` inside your form.

Comment: Write it to a form control before submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden number input inside of the form so the data will be passed onto the server:

```
<input type='hidden' id='totalCost' />
```

Then put in the total cost:

```
var totalCost = document.getElementById('totalCost');
totalCost.innerHTML = Price;
```

Then submit the form:

```
totalCost.form.submit();
```

Comment: Will this work with all the other fields? so instead of the `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">` button? with `<form action="register.php?changeme=yes" method="post" id="register">`

Comment: Yes it should, the code puts the values into hidden input elements that in the form. Only the input elements within the form are passed onto the server. I hope this answers your question it was a little unclear.